# Sympy, how to simplify an expression if part of it is known in an equation

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

For instance let's say I have the following code :

```
expre=t+C1-C2
equation=Eq(C3,C1-C2)
```

How to substitute `C1-C2` by their value `C3` that is getting this :

```
expre=t
```

Comment: You should use `subs` to replace expressions.